Why Can Only I Copy/Paste Files via Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V in Google Remote Desktop While Others Can’t?
I'm using Google Remote Desktop and can seamlessly copy and paste files between my local and remote desktops. For instance, I simply use Ctrl+C to copy a file from my local machine, switch to the remote desktop's file explorer, and use Ctrl+V to paste it there—and vice versa. This works perfectly for me.
However, my colleagues (3 of them) who connect to the same remote desktop are unable to do this. Here's the exact workflow they follow:

Use Ctrl+C to copy a file from their local machine's file explorer.
Switch to the remote desktop and open the file explorer.
Press Ctrl+V to paste the file into the remote desktop.

For them, nothing happens.
Additional details:

Clipboard synchronization is enabled.
Clipboard and Insecure content permissions are allowed in Chrome/Edge (chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2Fremotedesktop.google.com).
Chrome Remote Desktop Host (Control Panel): Version 131.0.6778.26.
Chrome Remote Desktop Extension (Browser): Version 2.1.
All of our settings are identical.

Despite this, I’m the only one who can transfer files this way. Is there a setting or configuration that I might have unknowingly enabled that they haven’t?
I’d appreciate any insights or suggestions—thanks in advance!
